# python and ip range?

Tags: python

For example, I have a file ( city and ip addresses ):

```
....
City1    31.25.87.0 - 31.25.87.15
 .... .... 
City2    31.47.224.0 - 31.47.255.255
....
```

How to know by ip adress city name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.icir.org/robin/pysubnettree/

you may need to convert ip ranges in cidr, so this library can help you

http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/

Please consider that converting ip ranges to cidrs you may have multiple cidr blocks so you have to repeat the city in the tree

Comment: Looks no method works to convert ip range to cidrs in python-iptools module. Find another module for converting  https://github.com/jathanism/cidrize/