# How quickly find ip address in range of IP addresses?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python and ip range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326655/python-and-ip-range)
>   [How to get list of IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338655/how-to-get-list-of-ip-addresses)

I have a many ip ranges in text file:

```
1.0.0.0 - 1.0.0.255
....
223.255.254.0 - 223.255.254.255
```

How to quickly find range for ip address ?

Comment: Please check your previous questions before asking more, I'm pretty sure my answer to your previous question negates this one, unless I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the dotted-ip-address to an integer using the build-in socket.
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66517-ip-address-conversion-functions-with-the-builtin-s/

And then do a test to see if you ip-address falls between the two integers:

```
a = dottedQuadToNum(ipfrom)
b = dottedQuadToNum(ipto)
mine = dottedQuadToNum(MyIP)
```

You can do a test to see if `mine` falls between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If IPs are sorted you can perform binary search on the IP's. So it will be O(logN) where N is the number of IP's in the list.

Answer (score 0):

[Python-iptools](http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/) seems to be a good tool for you :

It provides objects like :

> - **IpRange**: Range of ip addresses providing `in` and iteration.
> - **IpRangeList**: List of IpRange objects providing `in` and iteration.